# How can I run a simple Python script like PHP on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, python

I have a really simple Python script which I'd like to run on my Apache 2 server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print

print "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body></body></html>"
```

How can I *simply* get this up and going on my Apache server? I'm not looking to do anything fancy, I just want something that works.

Comment: You forgot the ' World' after 'Hello'.  It isn't official unless it is "Hello World".

Comment: If only it were that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a CGI script. Enable CGI on the server, call the script `whatever.py`, put it in the `cgi-bin/` directory, and go to `http://somehost.ex/cgi-bin/whatever.py`.